# Title for x and y axis in Flot graph

Tags: jquery, graph, flot

Is it possible to show title for x and y axis in flot graph?

Following is the code:

```
    $.plot($("#placeholder_1w"), [d], {
        series: {
        lines: { show: true, fill: false, fillColor: "red" },
        points: { show: true, fill: true,fillColor: "red"  }
    },
        grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true , color: 'green'},
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            minTickSize: [1, "day"],
            min: (myWeekDate).getTime(),
            max: (new Date()).getTime()
        },
        colors: ["red", "green", "#919733"]
    });
```

Comment: In addition to @Ryley's answer, there is also a plugin available:  https://github.com/markrcote/flot-axislabels

Comment: @Mark - make that an answer, I'd vote for it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Flot does not support axis labels by itself, but you can fairly easily add them using html and css, and a bit of modification to your flot options.

The demo on the [flot site](http://flotcharts.org) has a y axis label.  It is created by appending a div with certain classes to the flot container:

```
var xaxisLabel = $("<div class='axisLabel xaxisLabel'></div>")
  .text("My X Label")
  .appendTo($('#placeholder_1w'));

var yaxisLabel = $("<div class='axisLabel yaxisLabel'></div>")
  .text("Response Time (ms)")
  .appendTo($('#placeholder_1w'));
```

Then, you need CSS like this:

```
.axisLabel {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.xaxisLabel {
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.yaxisLabel {
    top: 50%;
    left: 2px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

If you need to support IE6/7, there's more trickery to deal with unfortunately - you'd want your body tag to be labelled with the class of "ie6" or "ie7" by doing something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]><body class="ie ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><body class="ie ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><body class="ie ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><body class="ie ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><body class="ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE ]><!--><body><!--<![endif]-->
```

And then this additional CSS:

```
.ie7 .yaxisLabel, .ie8 .yaxisLabel {
    top: 40%;
    font-size: 36px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.0, M12=0.33, M21=-0.33, M22=0.0,sizingMethod='auto expand');
}
```

Finally, in my attempts to do this, I found I needed to specify a fixed labelWidth for the y axis and a fixed labelHeight for the xaxis.

See a working example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/U82Dc/

Answer (score 5):

There is a plugin for flot out here: https://github.com/mikeslim7/flot-axislabels to implement axis labels.

However it is not supported in IE browsers less than version 9.0. @Ryley's solution is a cool one.

Comment: thanks @cederlof you saved my day Bimal this plugin is old and having some issues my issue resolved by using github.com/markrcote/flot-axislabels